# when using webclient.downloaddata(page) in page does it treat as i visit this page?

Tags: asp.net

my question is
from my site if i use webclient.downloaddata(page).Does it treats that i visited that page or not? it's very important to be used in google analytics

anyone has any answer?

Thanks advanced

Answer (score 1):

Whether you visit a page or execute WebClient.DownloadData, an HTTP GET request is sent to the server. From the server's point of view, they are exactly the same.

If you want to exclude calls made by DownloadData you can use a custom user-agent header  and set Google Analytics to filter out visits with this custom user-agent. See [here](http://blogs.keynote.com/the_watch/2011/09/filtering-out-web-performance-monitoring-traffic-from-google-analytics.html) for an example.

Comment: i want exactly that when using WebClient.DownloadData number of visitors increases in this page.so for ensure only if i used WebClient.DownloadData.It like that i visited this page and scripts of google runs normally in it.

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos : do you understand me or not?

Comment: I'm sure he does. Did you understand him?

Comment: i asked in my comment for ensure.I want clear answer Yes or not?